# FastAPI - can't access path parameters from middleware

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

My typical path is something like

```
/user/{user_id}/resource/{resource_id}
```

I have a validation method, already written in async python, like this:

```
async def is_allowed(user_id: int, resource_id: int) -> bool
```

That returns a boolean: true if the user can access the resource, false otherwise.

I want to write a `middleware` that calls `is_allowed` extracting the variables from the path.

I fiddled around but I can't find how to get them: I was expecting to get this information from `request.path_params`.

A somehow more complete example (edited following @Marcelo Trylesinski answer):

```
import logging

from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import Response

app = FastAPI()

_logger = logging.getLogger()
_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


async def is_allowed(user_id, resource_id):
    _logger.error(user_id)
    _logger.error(resource_id)
    return True


@app.middleware('http')
async def acl(request: Request, call_next):
    user_id = request.path_params.get("user_id", None)
    resource_id = request.path_params.get("resource_id", None)
    allowed = await is_allowed(user_id, resource_id)
    if not allowed:
        return Response(status_code=403)
    else:
        return await call_next(request)


@app.get('/user/{user_id}/resource/{resource_id}')
async def my_handler(user_id: int, resource_id: int):
    return {"what": f"Doing stuff with {user_id} on {resource_id}"}
```

The logged values are `None`.

Comment: For what I can see, the `path_params` are avilable only after the `call_next()` method returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve your goal with a Middleware, because Middlewares are executed before the routing.

Therefore FastAPI/Starlette doesn't know which path it will match to and cannot populate `path_params`.

You will have to use a different solution, such as passing these params on a cookie, header or query arg, or using a decorator/Dependency.

Reference:

https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/230

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/#middleware